# Join Order Optimization

Tags: optimization, trees, dynamic-programming

Consider the join: (σtitle=Overwatch Game)⨝ Event ⨝ rating ⨝ Player 
What is the optimal join order? 
Based on the schema on the following picture:
 [image: (schema)]

I am suppoused (and that's what I tried) to use Dynamic Programming to obtain the result. 
Considering only Deep-Left-Join Trees, and use the expected size (in number of rows) of intermediate results as costs.
How can I do this? 
I really appreciate your help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on "the **optimal** join order"? Do you want to the lowest number of tuples in the intermediate results?

Comment: Exactly @Apass.Jack